# Why is Paperclip giving me this "unknown attribute" error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, simple-form

I have...

**/config/routes.rb**:

```
resources :surveys do
  resources :screenshots
end
```

**/app/models/survey.rb**:

```
has_many :screenshots
```

**/app/models/screenshot.rb**:

```
attr_accessible :name, :shot, :screenshot, :result_ids
belongs_to :survey
has_many :results
has_attached_file :shot, :default_url => ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path('missing_:style.png')
```

**/db/schema.rb**:

```
create_table "screenshots", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "survey_id"
  t.boolean  "resetting_cache",   :default => false
  t.string   "url"
  t.string   "shot_file_name"
  t.string   "shot_content_type"
  t.integer  "shot_file_size"
  t.datetime "shot_updated_at"
  t.boolean  "include",           :default => false
  t.datetime "created_at",                           :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                           :null => false
  t.string   "name"
end
```

**/app/controllers/screenshots_controller.rb**:

```
def new
  @survey = Survey.find(params[:survey_id])
  @competitor = @survey.competitor
  @screenshot = Screenshot.new
end

def create
  @survey = Survey.find(params[:survey_id])
  @screenshot = Screenshot.new(params[:screenshot])
  @competitor = @survey.competitor
  flash[:notice] = "Screenshot was successfully added." if @screenshot.save
  respond_with(@survey, @screenshot)
end
```

**/app/views/screenshots/_form.html.haml**:

```
= simple_form_for [@survey, @screenshot] do |f|
  = f.error_notification
  = f.file_field :shot
  = f.association :results, :collection => @survey.selected_results
  = f.button :submit, :label => "Save", :id => "submit_screenshot"
```

Does anyone know why `@screenshot = Screenshot.new(params[:screenshot])` is giving me an `unknown attribute: screenshot` error?

Typical `params` at that point would be:

```
=> {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"t33SO+/mpPlQY/+7+5iRTe6O2zL/MtqisYXyghzkLY8=",
 "screenshot"=>
  {"screenshot"=>
    #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fd5cca0ace0
     @content_type="image/png",
     @headers=
      "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"screenshot[screenshot]\"; filename=\"youtube.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n",
     @original_filename="youtube.png",
     @tempfile=
      #<File:/var/folders/k9/vnpft_6d7qs6xmdb9_4svvmw0000gn/T/RackMultipart20131125-3030-1gmx1sy>>,
   "result_ids"=>["", "29857"]},
 "commit"=>"Create Screenshot",
 "action"=>"create",
 "controller"=>"screenshots",
 "survey_id"=>"14564"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"screenshot"=> #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fd5cca0ace0>
```

This parameter should be called `shot`, not `screenshot`. `shot` is what you named the attachment in the model.

Answer (score 0):

In your attr_accessible for the Screenshot model, you include :screenshot. Since this is the name of your model and not of an attribute in your model, you don't need to include it in attr_accessible. This is probably what's throwing it off.

Also, did you mean for your file name to be models/screenshot.rb, not models/screenshots?

Comment: Yes, `screenshot.rb`, thanks. Fixed that. When I remove `:screenshot` from the `attr_accessible` I get a `Can't mass-assign protected attributes: screenshot` error.

Comment: which rails are you using?

Comment: also can you post your form? are you nesting?

Comment: Rails 3.2.1. Sorry for not posting form earlier. Will post it now. Am not calling nested attributes as far as I can tell. Thanks.